# A my_model_path is generated with "?" and "&" instead of "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in routes:

```
get 'entities/:var1/:var2' => 'entities#show'
```

But this:

```
entities_path(var1: "fdsfds", var2: "fdsfdsfdsfds")
```

generates a url with ? and &. Why is that? Why not with "/"?

Comment: This is how routing works hash is considered as params which are passed after route with `?` and params are joined with `&`

Comment: So the above route should generate `/entities?var1=fdsfds&var2=fdsfdsfdsfds` which is correct

Answer (score 1):

Add this route in `routes.rb`

```
get 'entities/:var1/:var2', to: 'entities#show', as: 'custom_entities'
```

And call it with

```
custom_entities_path("fdsfds", "fdsfdsfdsfds")
```

This will now generate

```
entities/fdsfds/fdsfdsfdsfds
```

and now you will get

```
params[:var1] = "fdsfds"
# and 
params[:var1] = "fdsfdsfdsfds"
```